# Validating a new definition for detection

Tags: mcnemar-test, method-comparison, validity

I am having some trouble understanding what approach I would use to validate a new set of definitions versus the "gold standard" to detect disease positivity. For example, if I wanted to say participants in a cohort are COVID+ if they meet criteria A, B, and C (the new definition). Then compare those results to the "gold standard" whose definition is A, B, C, and D to determine if the new definition is feasible.

So far my understanding would be to calculate the sensitivity for both and do a McNemar test to see if they are significantly different. But would this be possible if the "gold standard" is 100% accurate? What would be my other options?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your gold standard seems to be the definition of having Covid or not.  So your new criteria can be judged against this, for example with sensitivity and selectivity.

Comment: Would a ROC curve be useful here?

Comment: An ROC curve could help you decide a cuttoff for your new citeria

Comment: So it is just as simple as calculating sensitivity and specificity? I guess I was over thinking it.